# Optimizing space usage in a trie structure in a java program

Tags: java, algorithm, project, trie

I am trying to implement a trie structure in Java with 203675 words for a text editor.

Before, I was using ArrayList to store the words and that was taking 90 megabytes of space. So I want to use a trie to minimize space consumption.

Here is what I have so far, but now space consumption is 250 megabytes.  What is the reason for this increase?

```
package TextEditor;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Vertex {
    int words;
    Map<Character, Vertex> child;
    public Vertex() {
        words = 0;
        child = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
class Trie {
    private Vertex root;
    private InputStream openFile;
    private OutputStream openWriteFile;
    private BufferedReader readFile;
    private BufferedWriter writeFile;
    public Trie() {
        root = new Vertex();
    }
    public Trie(String path) {
         try {
            root = new Vertex();
            openFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
            readFile = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(openFile));
            String in = readFile.readLine();
                    while(readFile.ready()) {
                        this.insert(in);
                    try {
                        in = readFile.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "TRIE CONSTRUCTION ERROR!!!!");
                    }
                    }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "TRIE CONSTRUCTION ERROR!!!!");
        }
    }
    private void addWord(Vertex vertex, String s, int i) {
        try {
        if(i>=s.length()) {
            vertex.words += 1;
            return;
        }
        char ind  = s.charAt(i);
        if(!vertex.child.containsKey(ind)) {
            vertex.child.put(ind, new Vertex());
        }
    addWord(vertex.child.get(ind), s, i+1);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    final void insert(String s) {
        addWord(root, s.toLowerCase(), 0);
    }
    private void DFS(Vertex v, String s, ArrayList list, 
        boolean store, String startsWith, int ind) {
    if(v != null && v.words != 0) {
            if(!store) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            else {
                if(s.length() >= startsWith.length()) {
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Vertex> entry : v.child.entrySet()) {
            Character c = entry.getKey();
            if((startsWith ==  null) || (ind>=startsWith.length()) || 
                (startsWith.charAt(ind) == c)) {
                    DFS(v.child.get(c), s + c, list, store, startsWith, ind+1);
             }
        }
    }
    public void Print() {
        DFS(root, new  String(""), null, false, null, 0);
    }
    ArrayList<String> getAsList(String startsWith) {
        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
        DFS(root, new  String(""), ret, true, startsWith, 0);
        return ret;
    }
    int count(Vertex  vertex, String s, int i) {
    if(i >= s.length()) {
            return vertex.words;
        }
    if(!vertex.child.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
            return 0;
        }
        return count(vertex.child.get(s.charAt(i)), s, i+1);
    }
    int count(String s) {   
        return count(root, s, 0);
    }
}
```

Is there a working example of a trie structure I can use?

Comment: You may want to use the Flyweight design pattern to store your characters.  If each character is a separate object, you will get an explosion of memory usage.  More information here: http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html

Comment: THe [tag:netbeans] tag and the reference to NetBeans in your title have been removed as your coding problem has *nothing* to do with NetBeans. You're not "programming with NetBeans", but rather you're programming with Java.

Comment: Generally, in heap issue situations, you could try two approaches: either runtime profiling, or getting a heap dump and analyzing that. That tells it for sure how much is being actually consumed. Also keep in mind that there is garbage collection happening - or not happening in the background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the word "space" is ambiguous.  Based on your description, it sounds like you're talking about the heap.  If so, the reason for the increased memory usage is that a data structure like a trie actually does take up extra memory to store its references between nodes.  An `ArrayList` just packs everything in, one `String` reference after another, and it doesn't have any additional information beyond how long the array is.  A trie has lots more bookkeeping to specify the relationships between all of the nodes.

In particular, the `HashMap` in each vertex is going to be extremely expensive; the Sun implementation allocates enough space for a 16-entry map by default, and that requires storage for the map's own memory-allocation record, `hashCodes` (32-bit `int`s, not `char`s), the object wrappers for each `Character`...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, separate the datastructure (your trie) from any code filling it. It just needs to hold the data in a structured form, and provide some basic functionality, that's it. Filling it should happen outside that datastructure itself so you can properly handle the streams. There is not a single good reason to have your trie fill itself by giving a path as a param.
To clarify my first point - pulling the filling out of the trie: **currently the streams gobble up a lot of memory inside the trie because they are held in private variables and the streams are never closed or destroyed. which means you keep the the file loaded in memory on top of the filled datastructure.** Otherwise garbage collection can clean up those items just like using the arraylist.

Please don't reinvent the wheel and use a basic implementation such as the following. Get it working with this basic setup, and worry about improving it later.

```
public class Trie {

    private Map<String, Node> roots = new HashMap<>();

    public Trie() {}

    public Trie(List<String> argInitialWords) {
            for (String word:argInitialWords) {
                    addWord(word);
            }
    }

    public void addWord(String argWord) {
            addWord(argWord.toCharArray());
    }

    public void addWord(char[] argWord) {
            Node currentNode = null;

            if (!roots.containsKey(Character.toString(argWord[0]))) {
                    roots.put(Character.toString(argWord[0]), new Node(argWord[0], "" + argWord[0]));
            }

            currentNode = roots.get(Character.toString(argWord[0]));

            for (int i = 1; i < argWord.length; i++) {
                    if (currentNode.getChild(argWord[i]) == null) {
                            currentNode.addChild(new Node(argWord[i], currentNode.getValue() + argWord[i]));
                    }

                    currentNode = currentNode.getChild(argWord[i]);
            }

            currentNode.setIsWord(true);
    }

    public boolean containsPrefix(String argPrefix) {
            return contains(argPrefix.toCharArray(), false);
    }

    public boolean containsWord(String argWord) {
            return contains(argWord.toCharArray(), true);
    }

    public Node getWord(String argString) {
            Node node = getNode(argString.toCharArray());
            return node != null && node.isWord() ? node : null;
    }

    public Node getPrefix(String argString) {
            return getNode(argString.toCharArray());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return roots.toString();
    }

    private boolean contains(char[] argString, boolean argIsWord) {
            Node node = getNode(argString);
            return (node != null && node.isWord() && argIsWord) || (!argIsWord && node != null);
    }

    private Node getNode(char[] argString) {
            Node currentNode = roots.get(Character.toString(argString[0]));

            for (int i = 1; i < argString.length && currentNode != null; i++) {
                    currentNode = currentNode.getChild(argString[i]);

                    if (currentNode == null) {
                            return null;
                    }
            }

            return currentNode;
    }
}

public class Node {

    private final Character ch;
    private final String value;
    private Map<String, Node> children = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean isValidWord;

    public Node(char argChar, String argValue) {
            ch = argChar;
            value = argValue;
    }

    public boolean addChild(Node argChild) {
            if (children.containsKey(Character.toString(argChild.getChar()))) {
                    return false;
            }

            children.put(Character.toString(argChild.getChar()), argChild);
            return true;
    }

    public boolean containsChildValue(char c) {
            return children.containsKey(Character.toString(c));
    }

    public String getValue() {
            return value.toString();
    }

    public char getChar() {
            return ch;
    }

    public Node getChild(char c) {
            return children.get(Character.toString(c));
    }

    public boolean isWord() {
            return isValidWord;
    }

    public void setIsWord(boolean argIsWord) {
            isValidWord = argIsWord;

    }

    public String toString() {
            return value;
    }

}
```

If you are considering memory usage improvements (at the cost of performance) you can do it in the following ways (seperate or combined)

- by switching the object Character to it's primitive char form, this will save you the overhead of the bytes used for the object aswell as any internal private variables
- by switching the value argument of a Node to type char[], you will save yourself another String object in each node
- by implementing trie compression and merging the common branches. This will eliminate the need for a bunch of nodes. How many nodes will be spared will depend on the actual content entry and the simularity between the entered words. The more simular words are, the less the trie can be compressed and less nodes will be spared. And thus less memory will be freed up
- by switching the hashmap implementation to a more memory friendly implementation (at the cost of lookup and insertion speed). The thing that would work best is a datastructure which wouldn't take more memory than it needs for holding the keys. For example: if a node is known to hold exactly 3 keys, an array of length 3 would be best for that node in terms of memory consumption. In practise, a sortedSet with a low start capacity should work better than a hashmap in terms of memory consumption because you skip the need for holding hashcodes but yet works easier to insert and search in than an array.

In general a well implemented trie, and I stress the well implemented should be about equal to the memory consumption of the 90Mb for the same dataset you are entering in it although it will depend entirely on the actual dataset.

If you managed to put together a list of words where most words aren't prefixes of any other word. Your memory usage will be far greater than with an ArrayList because you need way more nodes to represent the same thing.

If you really want to save some memory for a true random dataset, you should have a look at [Burst tries](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf), another viable alternative could be the patricia trie.

Comment: Good suggestions, but will any of what you suggest help the OP with the space issue?

Comment: It's not C++ so there will be some overhead. But as I said, this is a basic implementation.Depending on your needs, look at suffix tree which is great at full text search. In your case, I'd consider compressing the trie when you filled it. When the trie nodes are not keyed by node specific data (or if the node's data is common) it is possible to compress the trie representation by merging the common branches. This application is typically used for compressing lookup tables when the total set of stored keys is very sparse within their representation space.

Comment: I understand that it's not C++, and that there will be overhead.  But the OP's problem as presented is that his ArrayList implementation consumed 90MB, so he went to a Trie hoping for an improvement but it was worse (250 MB).  Will your suggestion be likely to reduce his memory utilization below the original 90 MB?

Comment: If you strip it down further as suggested above and below (replacing Character objects with char), replacing the hashmap with a sorted array/list (with low initial cap), or sorted set for example. You will ditch the need for hashcodes. This will make inserting and deleting a very costly operation though. Also implementing compression will cut down your nodes as far as possible. The only way to know for sure is to implement the suggested memory saving changes actually load in your file. Since I don't have your file, I can't do it for you.

Comment: also useful: http://www.abeel.be/content/java-memory-usage. It gives you an idea of what the replacement of Character vs char will do for memory consumption:

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm not the OP.   My point here is that you're not actually addressing the OP's issue, just giving advice.  Good advice (assuming some things are true about frequency of insertions and distribution of character usage), but I don't see any words in your answer that speak to memory utilization.

Comment: i did not get this part "Please don't reinvent the wheel". I did not reinvent the wheel and my implementation is as easy as yours and this data structure works the only problem is with space consumption.

Comment: Because you made your own implementation rather than starting from a tested existing one, you ended up with at least twice the memory consumption - see the point about streams - where this could have been prevented

Comment: i removed the stream objects  from the class as you told and only ran the trie file and loaded the words. Earlier it was taking 9.2 mb and now it is taking 9.1 mb. I think the problem is else where.

Comment: I must say, i'm surprised that they would have been cleaned up inside the trie since a reference was held there.

Comment: thanks for the burst trie pdf. i tried to up vote you but didn't have the required rep points v:(.